# What is the role of the spy on Tycho in "The Expanse" TV series?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, the-expanse-2015, the-expanse-novels

In the books there is no such spy on Tycho that sneaks onto Rocinante and then Eros. Why did the creators of the series add his character to the show?

Comment: I can't remember the book well enough to make this an answer, but my guess would be that he was added for exposition and drama. He tells them how to avoid being shot at by the martian ship, rather than having the main crew just know everything themselves. And he's an agent provocateur (or tries to be), who's exact motives are unknown to the audience; lots of scenes where he sows seeds of mistrust and such. And he's someone for others to interact with to better establish _their_ characters.

Comment: This is all supposition, but remember that Chrisjen did not exist as a character in book one.  As a result, from what I recall, the book was written from a more limited perspective of primarily Miller's and Holden's pov, and we do not actively see what Earth government is up to as much.  By adding the wider perspective of Chrisjen, it necessitated adding in details to show what Earth government was up to at all points.  So one of those new details took the form of the spy character.  The spy also as @Flambino said, served some other purposes that helped the story in other ways

Comment: I like both answers. I see that adding Avasarala and EarthGov at this point required some other changes to the plot.

Comment: Actually, neither of these are answers; they're _just_ comments. @Flambino why don't you expand your comment into an answer?

Comment: @Kai, why don't you?

Comment: @SQB I didn't want to write an answer, as I have no sources to back it up and haven't read the books (the character might exist in some form there, but I wouldn't know). So I can't truly answer the question of "Why did the creators add him?"; my comment is speculation and supposition. Hence why it's a comment, not an answer. I'd rather have someone who can cite sources or source material - like Kai, who appears to have read the books - post a proper answer.

Comment: The question is about why did the tv show creators make the choices they did.  We can make guesses why they might have based on comparisons with the show versus the books, but I know of no quotes by the show creators that say for sure why.  Hence, I did not make it an answer.